# JavaFX Game Issues with wall boundaries

Tags: javafx, boundary

I am having trouble getting my simple JavaFX Maze Game to work. I just wanted to do this to test how much I knew, and I have gotten almost to the end.

All I want to do now is see if there is a way for me to combine all of the Rectangle2D Boundaries into a single bounding shape for me to do collision detection with.

Right now, I have maze walls set up like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu4Ar.png), and I have to check for collision against every single one of the wall objects, which I have contained in a list.

What I want to know is there anyway of turning that into a single shape that I can check collision against. That would make my job so much easier when it comes to finishing my game.

**EDIT 1:** The red boxes in the image are just there to represent the Rectangle2D bounding boxes. They will not actually be there in the final product.

**EDIT 2:** All of these have been created using a simple black square sprite, and all of the bounding Rectangle2D boxes are using the `javafx.geometry` package, not the `javafx.scene.shape` package.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of the comment thread on Powercoder's answer, I was able to get it figured out. Instead of using `javafx.geometry` classes, I was able to switch to `javafx.scene.shape` classes, which allowed me to finish everything I was trying to do.

Here is my old code: https://pastebin.com/1DBXuq79

and here is my new code: https://pastebin.com/uXTrcsZ2

For anybody who wants to compare and figure out how I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [union](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#union-javafx.scene.shape.Shape-javafx.scene.shape.Shape-) many shapes into one?

Comment: That is similar to what I am looking for, but that is for using the `javafx.scene.shape` classes. I need to figure out how to do it for `javafx.geometry` classes.

Comment: Rly, I badly read EDIT 2. Looks like JavaFX doesn't imply such using of [geometry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/package-frame.html). Can you say why need to use this package but not `scene.shape`? Maybe I could help to transfer the solution to `shape`.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily HAVE to be `geometry`, I was just following the tutorial here: [link](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835). In the tutorial, they use the `geometry` classes, but they don't give a particular reason why. I think it might be because the `shape` classes don't contain the `intersects()` method for checking collision. If there is a way to get that method while using `scene.shape` I would be all for it.

Comment: You can use [`intersects()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#intersects-double-double-double-double-) for `Shape`. One of it's overloads takes `Bounds` as argument so it will be looking like `shape1.intersects(shape2.getBoundsInLocal()`.

Comment: I have been fiddling with this for a while. It seems like it would work, but now I can't seem to figure out how to allow the player to move. [Here is my code so far](https://pastebin.com/pc1JCevp). I would love if you could help me figure out how to allow the movement of the `player` circle.

Comment: here is my updated code: https://pastebin.com/8zjPdNpf - EDIT: I realized part of the problem was I forgot to say if not intersecting move, but now I can't move at all, possibly because the bounds completely contains the player circle because of the way I combined the walls.

Comment: I eventually got it to work. Instead of union, I used shapes in a list instead of geometry in a list. Now my game works perfectly! Thank You!